# How to incorporate variables in defaults?

Tags: terraform

I've the following code snippet, where the goal is to create a random ID and use it in naming projects.

```
  7 resource "random_id" "ent_id" {
  8     byte_length = 8
  9 }
 10
 23 variable "project_name" {
 24         type = "string"
 25         default = "proj-$${random_id.ent_id.hex}"
 26         description = "Name of the service project"
 27 }
```

Looks good syntactically, but when i run init, i get this-

```
Error: module.folder.google_project.new_project: "proj-$${random_id.ent_id.hex}" name must be 4 to 30 characters with lowercase and uppercase letters, numbers, hyphen, single-quote, double-quote, space, and exclamation point.
```

Am I missing something here? Is the error for the string "proj-$${random_id.ent_id.hex}" or the result of the that expression which comes to (or at least intended to come to) something like "proj-b7bb04fde7253b14"

Please note the '$$' in the expression is due to this- https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/18069

Comment: That behavior is supported in the 0.12 beta. What version are you using?

Comment: 0.11.13. So does that mean variable interpolation in default values is not supported below 0.12?

Comment: According to that Github issue you linked to: yes. Before then, you are going to almost certainly have to use a `locals` instead.

Comment: Can't use '''locals''' either. Because then I'd have to assign the local variable to default (default = "${local.folder_id}"). And default does not support interpolations. I guess there is no way to set default's value as a 'variable'.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the issue correctly as I'm quite new to Terraform, but to me $$ will be replaced by $ instead of interpolating the content. You'll end up with a variable with value "proj-${random_id.ent_id.hex}" instead of the expected proj-XXXXXXXX where XXXXXXXX is your random ID.

Comment: the expression default = "proj-${random_id.ent_id.hex}" gives the error- Error: variable "project_name": default may not contain interpolations

Answer (score 0):

did not try to use a resource from the variable default (i find it an odd lifecycle) but here's a workaround for whoever needs it:

```
# optional variable for customer
variable "suffix" {
  type        = string
  default     = null
}
```

```
locals{
  # provide random value as a fallback to customer value
  suffix = var.suffix == null ? random_id.suffix[0].id : var.suffix
}


resource "random_id" "suffix" {
  count       = var.suffix == null ? 1 : 0
  byte_length = 3
}
```

```
resource "foo" "bar"{
  id = local.suffix
}
```